# Main effects and interaction effects - direction?

Tags: lme4-nlme, interaction, main-effects

just a quick question regarding main effects and interaction effects:

For example, in a LME model like

```
lme_model <- lmer(outcome ~ Group*Time + var1 + (1|Sub), data=datatable
```

In the analysis there would be main effects of *group*, *time* (and *var1*), correct? *Group x Time* (or *Group:Time* , does it matter how I write it btw?) would then be called an interaction effect, if I am not mistaken?
Someone told me that *main effects are without direction*. Is that correct? I am pretty sure I am getting I direction shown in the output of `summary(lme_model)`. The interaction effect also has a direction effect, hasn't it?

Maybe the other person used `anova(lme_model)` to get to that opinion, which instead of `summary(lme_model)` doesn't produce estimates and a direction for main and interaction effects?

Edit: with *direction* I meant positive or negative, e.g. *there is a negative groupXtime interaction effect*

Comment: I think it really depends on what you mean by direction here. Point estimates from regression coefficients usually give an idea of how a predictor decreases or increases a conditional mean value, which is your outcome variable. Interaction coefficients do the same thing really as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "direction" you mean "sign" (positive or negative). Then yes, all coefficients — the main effects and the interaction — have a sign.

The sign of the main effect for a variable that interacts with other variables might not be particularly easy to interpret on its own. Same goes for the interaction.

Say the model is $\operatorname{E}\{Y\} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2$. When $x_2$ changes by one unit, $\operatorname{E}\{Y\}$ changes by $\beta_2 + \beta_3x_1$. The expected change in the response depends on the coefficients $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ (and their signs) as well as on the (fixed) value of $x_1$.

There is an easier way to visualize and understand the effects of a predictor that works equally well in models with and without interactions: partial effect plots.

Here is how to create a partial effect plot in R using the [ggeffects](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/index.html) package.

```r
library("ggeffects")

set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

# Generate data with an interaction between x1 (categorical) and x2 (continuous)
data <-
  data.frame(
    x1 = sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace = TRUE),
    x2 = rnorm(n)
  )
data$y <- ifelse(data$x1 == "A", 1 + data$x2, 2 - data$x2 / 3) + rnorm(n)

# Fit the model
model <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data = data)

# Make a partial effect plot for the continuous variable, x2,
# at each level of the categorical variable, x1
plot(
  ggpredict(model, terms = c("x2", "x1"))
)
#> Loading required namespace: ggplot2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank for the answer; also ggpredict looks very neat!